# validate form with checkform session?

Tags: php, forms, validation, session

How to validate form value ?

step my code working

1. fill user like "aaaa" in input create user. and click "Check user" button
2. fill name and last name in input
3. click "OK" button

Why checkform wiill show "Please enter User name." ??

test_1.php

```
    <?PHP
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
?>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#ff').form({
                success:function(data){
                    $.messager.alert('Info', data, 'info');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<form id="ff" name="form_check_user" method="post" action="test_2.php" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data">
Create User : <input type="text" name="user"/>
    <input type="submit" name="check_user" value="check user" />
</form>

<div style=" border-top: 1px solid #eee; width: 39%;"></div>
<br>

<form name="finished" method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
    Name : <input type="text" name="name"/>
    Last Name : <input type="text" name="last_name"/>
<br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK" />
</form>


    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function checkform ( form )
    {
      if (form.name.value == "") {
        alert( "Please enter your name." );
        form.name.focus();
        return false ;
      }
      if (form.last_name.value == "") {
        alert( "Please enter your last name." );
        form.last_name.focus();
        return false ;
      }
      if ("<?php echo $_SESSION[check];?>"  == "") {
        alert( "Please enter User name." );
        form.last_name.focus();
        return false ;
      }
    return true ;
    }
    //-->
    </script>
```

test_2.php

```
<?PHP
    session_start();
     $_SESSION["check"] = $_POST['user'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are accessing an undefined constant on your session variable like this..

```
if ("<?php echo $_SESSION[check];?>"  == "") { // See it is just check , you need to wrap it around quotes.
```

It should be

```
if ("<?php echo $_SESSION['check'];?>"  == "") {
```